git problem: unknow subcommand -- usage: git remote?
I am using git and having this problem : it gave me this error error:
unknown subcommand: `https://github.com/anhbui2975/cypressuploaddownload'
usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]

I used all the command to make my git to be refresh, but it is still like this. How can I fix this?
Could you please give me some advices? Thank you in advance.

What command did you type to get this error?

I guess you're attempting to do something like:
$ git remote https://github.com/anhbui2975/cypressuploaddownload
error: unknown subcommand `https://github.com/anhbui2975/cypressuploaddownload'
usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]
   or: git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--tags | --no-tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
   ...

That is wrong because quite literally, it's not a valid subcommand. You could type gibberish and get the same output:
$ git remote sldkfjsldkfjassdfghskdjfg
error: unknown subcommand `sldkfjsldkfjassdfghskdjfg'
...

Since you're trying to "refresh" the repository, I assume you  mean:
git remote add origin https://github.com/anhbui2975/cypressuploaddownload
git pull origin master

